# How to parse (infinite) nested object notation?

Tags: javascript, parsing, object, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am currently breaking my head about transforming this object hash:

```
"food": {
    "healthy": {
        "fruits": ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges'],
        "vegetables": ['salad', 'onions']
    },
    "unhealthy": {
        "fastFood": ['burgers', 'chicken', 'pizza']
    }
}
```

to something like this:

```
food:healthy:fruits:apples
food:healthy:fruits:bananas
food:healthy:fruits:oranges
food:healthy:vegetables:salad
food:healthy:vegetables:onions
food:unhealthy:fastFood:burgers
food:unhealthy:fastFood:chicken
food:unhealthy:fastFood:pizza
```

In theory it actually is just looping through the object while keeping track of the path and the end result.

Unfortunately I do not know how I could loop down till I have done all nested.

```
var path;
var pointer;
function loop(obj) {
    for (var propertyName in obj) {
        path = propertyName;
        pointer = obj[propertyName];

        if (pointer typeof === 'object') {
            loop(pointer);
        } else {
            break;
        }        
    }
};

function parse(object) {
    var collection = [];

};
```

There are two issues which play each out:

1. If I use recurse programming it looses the state of the properties which are already parsed.
2. If I do not use it I cannot parse infinite.

Is there some idea how to handle this?

Regards

Comment: Pass the state forward in the recursive call.

Comment: @user1689607 could you provide an example? Does that not crash when it begins to reloop the root properties again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your recursive function doesn't work is you're storing the state outside it. You want the state *inside* it, so that each invocation tracks its state.

Something like this:

```
var obj = /* ... the object ... */;
var lines = loop([], "", obj);

function loop(lines, prefix, obj) {
    var key, sawOne = false;

    // Is it an array?
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]") {
        // Yes, in your example these are all just strings to put
        // at the end, so do that
        for (key = 0; key < obj.length; ++key) {
             lines.push(prefix + ":" + obj[key]);
        }
    }
    else {
        // No, it's an object. Recurse for each property, adding the
        // property to the prefix we use on each line
        for (key in obj) {
            loop(lines, prefix ? (prefix + ":" + key) : key, obj[key]);
        }
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Completely off-the-cuff and untested, but you get the idea.

Edit: But apparently it works, as [Michael Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602554/michael-jasper) was kind enough to make a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/ucoyel/6) ([source](http://jsbin.com/ucoyel/6/edit)) which I've tweaked slightly.